# How to concatenate parts of a string?

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, concatenation, string-concatenation

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "Hello"; 
    string s = str[0] + str[1];  
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this code gives an error, even if we can concatenate strings?

Comment: Because `str[0]` and `str[1]` are single `char` entities. And adding two `char` values is simple and plain integer addition.

Comment: By the way, [never include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h), and [`using namespace std;` is a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 3):

the reason this fails

```
std::string s = str[0] + str[1];
```

is because `str[0]` and `str[1]` return a `char` (`H` and `e`):

```
std::string s = 'H' + 'e';
```

and adding two `char`s will not concatenate them, instead their values will be added together. Every character has an assigned number (look up ASCII table)

```
std::string s = 72 + 101;
```

and this will fail, as assigning the number 173 to a `string` doesn't really make sense to the compiler.

---

there are multiple ways to concatenate variables together, in this case the most simple solution would be

```
std::string s { str[0], str[1] };
```

This will be limited to `char`s though, so you couldn't say `{ str[0], str[1], 500 }`. Therefore the general way to concatenate any number of data, is to use [`std::ostringstream`](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=c%2B%2B+ostringstream), found in the header `<sstream>`. This how it is used:

```
std::ostringstream stream;
stream << str[0] << str[1] << 500;

std::string s = stream.str();
```

---

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why `using namespace std;` is considered bad practice and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) why `<bits/stdc++.h>` is to be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

`str[0]` and `str[1]` are giving you characters, not strings. Adding them gives you another character, which cannot be casted to a string.

You can construct a new string with a substring of the first part of the string you want to concatenate, and then insert the substring of the second part of the string you want to concatenate, like so:

```
// Construct new string that contains the first character of str
string s(str.begin(), str.begin() + 1);

// Add the second character of str onto the end of s
s.insert(s.end(), str.begin() + 1, str.begin() + 2);
```

Comment: Or you could just do `std::string s = std::string({str[0], str[1]});`

Comment: Yes, if you're only doing one character at a time. Better yet would be `string s{ str[0], str[1] };` Gets rid of the temporary. The iterator thing is just for scalability. Of course, you'd have to change the `+ 1`s and the `+ 2`s, but still.